# Can't add file to tar: archive/tar: sockets not supported

Tags: tar, docker, archive

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask but I am running a `docker build` command which is building an image on a mounted Volume. During the process I get this weird error

> Can't add file /mnt/Volumes/file/on/volume to tar: archive/tar: sockets not supported

What does this mean?

Comment: Looks like `/mnt/Volumes/file/on/volume` is a [UNIX domain socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket), you can verify this with the output of `file /mnt/Volumes/file/on/volume`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you really like to archive this file, I recommend you to use the dump extensions from `star`

Call:

```
star -C /mnt -c -dump Volumes > /tmp/file.tar
```

to archive all file types. If you like to be more complete with your backup, add:

```
-sparse

-acl

-xattr
```

With `-dump`, star uses the `exustar` format that has been designed for accurate incremental backups.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. I tried to do docker commit and I got the message

```
  ERRO[2018-10-06T20:54:22.894911981-05:00] Can't add file /var/lib/docker/overlay2/161e218868241d450115fafcadc20b52ad2c81bf2e6b83897d3dfb7081eea34d/diff/tmp/ssh-OOMPJg4ESVMk/agent.165 to tar: archive/tar: sockets not supported
```

I attached to the container again and deleted `/tmp/ssh-OOMPJg4ESVMk/`  then it committed just fine.

What is happening is something created a socket. For example the command `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` creates a socket and I didn't realize it.

Delete the sock file and it commits.

Comment: I noticed that even with the error it still commits.